# Rep cap breaks sometimes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-recalc

> [image]
>   It is [Jukka Suomela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383299/jukka-suomela)

or

> [image]
>   And it is [MichaelT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12166/michaelt)

Despite the fact the rep recalc is automatic now.

Comment: Did you have a negatively voted post deleted perhaps for the second example?

Comment: @Flexo It is not my rep. One second, I'll tell you whose rep is this.

Comment: @Flexo I edited.

Comment: Note that the *downvotes* these accounts placed *are not public*. The +1 and +2 are compensating for -1 downvotes on answers they placed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A! Understood. Really, down votes are invisible, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information missing are the -1 you get when downvoting an answer. That information is private so you won't ever see these listed.